# Error while opening site in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site

We have sharepoint2010 in our environment. when i'am trying to open sharepoint site from IE/Chrome it gives me an error

When i open central administration i find notification saying Some critical issues.

[image: eter image description here]

Here is the Log File

> https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1B2CB25B9690C6E9!114&authkey=!AGtp8v0hv31U0ic&ithint=file%2clog

Please advice. .

Comment: do know about this id 'CHALLANGER\administrator'.is it app pool id or farm admin or something else

Comment: challanger - DC name ( farm admin )

Comment: Looks like this account dont have permission on profile db? Did you created a new User Profile service or deleted the any?

Comment: No i didnt made any changes :/

Comment: can you check from central admin > upgrade and migration > review database status> any database called ProfileDatabase

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1B2CB25B9690C6E9!115&authkey=!AAk8HL1Hx_bpmNY&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

Comment: that is the problem, Looks like you Profile DB and Social DB are not repsonding. Please restore them...i will put more detail in answer

Comment: i have full backups from SP. how do i restore Profile DB and Social DB from it ? please add detailed answer thanx :)

Comment: I just added.Please check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Log and Image you shared. Looks like the Below Database are deleted / offline on SQL server.

- Profile DB
- Social DB

Both DBS are very important in order to smooth Sharepoint operations.Now you have two options.

- Restore these DBs from Backup or fix the issue with them so that their status should be online.
- Or delete the current UPA and create a new UPA.

Comment: I'am trying to restore from a full backup file.
Is this the one i need to restore
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1B2CB25B9690C6E9!115&authkey=!AAk8HL1Hx_bpmNY&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

Comment: ok, as long as they will be restored your site will be fine. please run the full sync after the restore

Comment: Can i ask other question or am i wasting you guys time. Im totally new here sry

Comment: not wasting of time....we are here to help in good faith...in rewards we want some up vote and marked as answer....but if question is not within your intial question then create a new questions, as it will get more visibility.

Comment: I restored DB successfully, how do i sync now? by command line ?

Comment: You have to go inside the User profile sync and start the full sync...centrral  admin> application management> manager service application > click on User profile service and on this page you will see the option

Comment: also dont forget to upvote,

Comment: Its working fine without sync.. :D Thanx everything is back now .
Already upvoted :P

Comment: it will but i would recommend the full sync....you marked it as answer along with this you have to click up arrow button.

Comment: Sry, to upvote i think i need to have atleast 15 Rep.
anyway ill sync User profiles

Comment: Oh, i think you have but ni issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some database availability or permission issues.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "Profile DB" requested by the login. The login failed.  Login failed for user 'CHALLANGER\administrator
```

Can you please check to make sure 'Profile DB' is online and available and that the above user has access to it? Same issue with 'Social DB'. Search your log file for `login failed` to see all instances.

Comment: There no such DB in SQL Server

Comment: Ok, if you don't have backups, then my suggestion would be to go into Central Administration and delete the User Profile Service Application. If you need it, create a new UPSA.

Comment: I do have Full backups

Comment: In that case, the alternate solution is to simply restore the UPSA databases to SQL Server. The backups will contain the permissions previously assigned. Once you restore the databases, the login failed messages should disappear [after a short period of time].

Comment: Overwrite the existing one?

Comment: You indicated they weren't on the SQL Server, so there should be nothing to overwrite.

Comment: Thanx #Trevor its up and running  :D